# Pass dynamic search arguments to filter in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

I have different filter criteria for a Movie json. 
Say for example if it's 'genre' it is:

```
filter: {'genre' : search}
```

Or for 'year' it will be:

```
filter: {'year' : search}
```

But since I am using pagination and for overall search, I am calling filter as a service within my controller like this:

```
$scope.$watch('search', function(search) {
    filteredmovies = filterFilter(_.values(movies), search);
    $scope.PaginationService.TotalItems = _.size(filteredmovies);
});
```

'search' is my ng-model on a textbox. The above lines does an overall search(not key based). Now I am confused how can I search for specific key properties like 'genre' and 'year' on movie, using this function filterFilter because users can select what properties they want to tie their search.

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is here, and you don't have enough code or any examples of what you are expecting to make a guess as to what the issue might be.

Comment: I have edited the question. My aim is to filter for specific key properties on my movie.json, using the filterFilter since I am using pagination.

Comment: where are the users selecting which field they want to search by?

Comment: Just like you're doing in the vew: filterFilter(_.values(movies), {genre: search});

Comment: It's a dropdown users first select and then type

Comment: @JBNizet  Thanks it works! But how can I use this dynamically, I mean storing the key in a var and then using it, because it is dynamic and I have numerous keys

Comment: `var criteria = {}; criteria[key] = search; filterFilter(_.values(movies), criteria);`.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks it worked perfectly. I was confused how to use it.